# Steps to deploy a custom document converter to Sharepoint and consume it in a Sharepoint web application

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a sample application which converts pdf to images. I want to install this application as a “Document Converter” ino Sharepoint 2010. I want to know the steps to convert my application as a document converter and deploy it as a feature and then access it from my Sharepoint web application

using SharePoint Object Model. How can I call a custom document converter from my Sharepoint web application using Sharepoint Object Model. How can I pass the document(pdf file in the document library to be converted into image) as a parameter to document converter from my Sgarepoint web application using Sharepoint Object model.

Comment: Hi! If you solved your problem, posting your solution might be helpful to other people who might arrive here from a search engine or so ;-) Thanks for them!

Answer (score 1):

Although not easy, looks like it´s well documented ..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms544523.aspx
;)

Answer (score 0):

Following this guide this becomes pretty simple
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497322(v=office.14).aspx

In short words

1. Create a new empty SharePoint 2010 project **and deploy as farm solution**
   [image]
2. Right click on the project name and choose Add > New Item. Select the "Empty Element" item and name it to something
   [image]
3. Open the elements.xml in the empty element you just created and add your document converter
   [image]
4. Ensure the feature scope including the module is set to WebApplication
   [image]

Thats it, deploy and have fun